# C: dynamic declare array size

Tags: c

I have the following declaration inside a function

```
int f[20000]
```

I want the number 20000 to be dynamic, How can i declare such array in code?

To be more specific, I have the following code to calculate PI.

```
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <stdio.h> 

#define BITS 2000
int a=10000,b,c=BITS*7/2,d,e,f[BITS*7/2+1],g; 

int main() 
{   
    for(;b-c;) 
        f[b++]=a/5; 
    for(;d=0,g=c*2;c-=14,printf("%.4d",e+d/a),e=d%a) 
        for(b=c;d+=f[b]*a,f[b]=d%--g,d/=g--,--b;d*=b);     
    //getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

I changed to

```
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <stdio.h> 

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{   
    //
    // .... omit some lines here
    // read bits from user input at runtime
    // say precision = 200
    //
    int a=10000,b,c=precision *7/2,d,e,f[precision *7/2+1],g; 
    for(;b-c;) 
        f[b++]=a/5; 
    for(;d=0,g=c*2;c-=14,printf("%.4d",e+d/a),e=d%a) 
        for(b=c;d+=f[b]*a,f[b]=d%--g,d/=g--,--b;d*=b);     
    //getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

It doesn't work, I googled then changed to

```
int a=10000,b,c=precision *7/2,d,e,g; 
int *f=calloc(precision *7/2+1, sizeof(int));
```

It still doesn't work, I mean the program doesn't crash, the value it calculated is not correct. What's wrong? Thank you.

Comment: Please define `It still doesn't work`

Comment: What is the value in precision. Where are you reading the user value for precision.

Comment: a 20000 * sizeof int array, (80000 bytes) on the stack is a very bad idea.  probably resulting in an overflow of the stack.  suggest: int arraySize = 20000;  int *pf = malloc( arraySize*sizeof int);  (then check that 'pf' does not contain NULL)  (be sure to use: 'free(pf);' when done with the array

Comment: this code does not cleanly compile.  a couple of the reasons are the parameters argc and argv are not used.  suggest using 'int main(void)

Comment: the ''7/2' is performing an integer divide, so the result will always be '3' not 3.5'

Comment: It's `precision*7/2` so as long as `precision` is an even number, the division is fine.

Comment: 'precision' is not defined,   So code does not compile   Suggest NOT trying to get everything on one line.  That makes the code difficult to debug, difficult to understand, etc suggest making use of vertical and horizontal white space, for readability/maintainability

Comment: the constants '7/2' will be handled at compile time.  so the result is 3, not 3.5  However, the code could use:  (precision * 7) / 2  then the error would never be greater than +/- 1

Comment: @SouravGhosh It doesn't work because the value it calculated is not correct.

Comment: @user3629249 yeah, i just removed the code aren't useful

Comment: well, the variable 'e' is not initialized on the first printf() and will be 0 (or close to it) for the next ~10000 iterations of the first 'for' loop   the returned value from the printf() is what controls the for loop.  the format "%.4d" will always return a >0 value so the second/outer 'for' loop might never exit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways to achieve what you want.

1. use dynamic memory allocation. [`malloc()`/`calloc()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc)
2. use [variable-length array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) (in `c99`)

That said, as pointed out by **@user3386109**, the problem in your second code snippet is use of uninitiated variable `b`. You may want to explicitly initialize the local variables before using their value.

Answer (score 3):

You get a dynamically sized array by allocating on the heap using malloc (or calloc).

Replace

```
int f[20000];
```

with

```
int *f = (int *) malloc(20000 * sizeof(int) );
```

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that global variables are guaranteed to be initialized to `0` (unless initialized to some other value). But local variables are garbage unless you initialize them. So the problem is that variable `b` starts out as garbage in the second snippet.

In the original code:

```
int a=10000,b;
int main(void)
{
}
```

`a` will start with the value `10000` because you initialized it, and `b` will start as `0` because it is an uninitialized **global** variable.

In the changed code:

```
int main(void)
{
    int a=10000,b;
}
```

`a` will start with the value `10000` because you initialized it, and `b` will start as some random value (e.g. `0x5315fe`) because it is an uninitialized **local** variable.

Comment: the question was NOT 'what is wrong with my code>', (of which there are lots of things wrong).  the question was 'how to dynamically size an array?'

Comment: The question itself had two perfectly good ways to dynamically allocate an array, but from the OP's point-of-view neither appeared to work. So then the question does become, "Why doesn't this code work?"

Answer (score -1):

Replace int f[2000]

with

int *f = new int[2000];

then use the array as f[0] = 1, f[1] = 2 etc...

when finished free up memory with delete [] f;

the array size could be allocated by a variable

eg.
int x = 2000;
 f = new int[x];

Comment: This question is tagged `c` and AFAIK, `new` is not `c`.